# CPAN module to access OpenSSL (en/de)crypt (cipher) operations

Tags: perl, openssl, cpan

I'm looking for a perl (CPAN) module to access OpenSSL's (en/de)cryption functions. Something entirely equivalent to piping through `openssl enc ...` (using the *openssl* binary) but without the overhead of fork/exec of a subprocess.

So far all the modules that I can find are more interested in implementing SSL or TLS, with all the associated communication and overheads. I am aware of [`Crypt::CBC`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt%3a%3aCBC), and the various compatible cipher modules such as [`Crypt::OpenSSL::AES`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt%3a%3aOpenSSL%3a%3aAES), but this does the bulk of the work in perl, only calling the underlying (C) libraries for one block at a time, and this is too slow.

Comment: How about [Net::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for a Perl equivalent to this:

**Encryption**

```
$ openssl enc -bf -in file.txt -out file.bf
enter bf-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter bf-cbc encryption password:

$ cat file.bf
Salted__��k^,�2�.�t�af/
```

**Decryption**

```
$ openssl enc -bf -d -in file.bf -out file.txt-2
enter bf-cbc decryption password:

$ cat file.txt-2 
test
```

As per https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html.

---

The Perl equivalent would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Crypt::CBC;
use IO::All;
use IO::Prompter;

my $in_file = shift || die "Usage: $0 'input file'";

my $password = prompt('enter bf-cbc encryption password:', -echo => '');

my $check_password = prompt('Verifying - enter bf-cbc encryption password:', -echo => '');

if ($password ne $check_password) {
    die "Verify failure - passwords do not match\n";
}

my $file_contents = io($in_file)->slurp;

my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -key => $password,
    -cipher => 'OpenSSL::Blowfish',
);

my $encrypted = $cipher->encrypt($file_contents);

say $encrypted;

say "-" x 80;

my $decrypted = $cipher->decrypt($encrypted);

say $decrypted;

exit 0;
```

Which outputs the following:

```
$ $ cat file.txt
test

$ ./openssl-enc-perl.pl file.txt
enter bf-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter bf-cbc encryption password:
Salted__�>4�>
=1vn6�
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test
```

It is clear that it is not forking from the following strace output:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 23.68    0.002480           8       295       220 stat
 16.52    0.001730          14       122           read
  8.32    0.000871          12        71         3 open
  6.21    0.000650          14        45           mmap
  6.01    0.000629           8        75        48 ioctl
  5.30    0.000555           5       105         3 lseek
  4.92    0.000515          64         8           select
  4.56    0.000478           7        68           close
  3.91    0.000409          29        14           write
  3.91    0.000409          12        34           mprotect
  3.63    0.000380           8        48           brk
  3.08    0.000323           4        74         1 rt_sigaction
  1.73    0.000181          20         9         9 access
  1.72    0.000180           8        22           fstat
  0.89    0.000093           4        22           geteuid
  0.78    0.000082          10         8           rt_sigprocmask
  0.77    0.000081           4        20           getegid
  0.75    0.000079           4        18           getuid
  0.74    0.000078          39         2           munmap
  0.74    0.000077          26         3         1 execve
  0.70    0.000073           4        18           getgid
  0.33    0.000035          35         1           readlink
  0.27    0.000028          14         2           arch_prctl
  0.22    0.000023          23         1           lstat
  0.17    0.000018           5         4           fcntl
  0.15    0.000016           4         4           getgroups
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.010473                  1093       285 total
```

This example requires:

1. [IO::All](https://metacpan.org/release/IO-All)
2. [IO::Prompter](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aPrompter)
3. [Crypt::CBC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt%3a%3aCBC)
4. [Crypt::OpenSSL::Blowfish](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt%3a%3aOpenSSL%3a%3aBlowfish)

But really all you need is the two Crypt modules. The IO modules can be replaced with their pure Perl equivalents if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer but if you look at my original question you can see that I am already aware of how to use Crypt::CBC with a suitable cipher module. The problem with that solution is that it is too slow because too much ends up being done in perl. Crypt::CBC passes data to/from the  cipher a block (typically 64 bytes) at a time.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood, I thought that Crypt::Blowfish was doing too much of the work in Perl and Crypt::OpenSSL::Blowfish was the answer to your prayers. Sorry man! Have you tried increasing the blocksize with the -blocksize parameter? You could try benchmarking different blocksizes against your real data set with [Dumbbench](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dumbbench).